# Немного представления о array(); и foreach(); для новичка

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, мастера!

Я начинающий веб-мастер в сфере программирования, и хотелось бы узнать и получить немного представления об `array();` и `foreach();`.

Есть следующий код:

```
$array = array();

foreach ($file[1] as $key => $value)
{
    $array['file'][] = [
        'bla-bla-bla' => $file[1][$key],
        'bla-bla-bla2' => $file[2][$key],
 ];
}
```

Так вот, могли бы объяснить этот код в понятном языке?

Также вопрос: если убрать `$array = array();`, то все равно работает. Почему? Или это необязательно в моем случае? Что он вообще делает? Создает пустой массив или что?

P.S: В оф. сайтах куча информации, но там, к сожалению, мне ничего не понятно.

Comment: Спасибо за поправку :)

Comment: Вопрос "что это за код?" - это не вопрос. Нужно уточнить что именно Вы уже понимаете о массивах и функции foreach и сформировать конкретные чёткие вопросы.

Comment: О массивах знаю, что это тип или структура данных в виде набора компонентов, а foreach отвечает за перебора массивов. Если убрать $array = array(); то все равно работает. Почему?

Comment: `$array = array();` - это просто инициализация пустого массива. Всё равно что написать `$string = '';` если убрать эту строку то будет работать, потому что в php необязательно инициировать переменные до начала их наполнения и если Вы уберете эту строку то `$array` инициируется уже внутри `foreach()`

Comment: Спасибо за понятный ответ! Еще вопрос, а как объяснили бы это? $array['file'][] =

Comment: Но лучше не убирать ибо он скорее всего используеться ниже и если массив для перебора пуст, то вы получите ошибку undefined variablen

Comment: Сейчас если его убирать, то подобной ошибки не вижу. "ибо он скорее всего используеться ниже" - что имеется ввиду, можно детальнее?

Comment: `$array['file'][] =` - заполнение двумерного массива. В ячейку 'file' добавляется ещё одна ячейка со значением массива `[
        'bla-bla-bla' => $file[1][$key],
        'bla-bla-bla2' => $file[2][$key],
 ]`. 
`ибо он скорее всего используеться ниже` - имеется в виду что в цикл `foreach` программа может и не зайти (если массив `file[1]` пуст), а дальше в коде возможно используется чтение из массива `$array`. И если убрать первую строку где инициируется `$array`, то код выведет ошибку

Comment: Спасибо) "если убрать первую строку где инициируется $array" - имеете ввиду $array = array(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Строка 1. Инициализация массива, работает без нее, потому что пхп не требует инициализации а проводит ее сам при использовании.

```
$array = array();//инициализация, пхп ее не требует

foreach ($file[1] as $key => $value)//перебираем все элементы элемента 
массива $file по ключу и значению, исходя из этого этот массив имеет такую 
структуру: Массив([1]=>Массив(...) [2]=>Массив(...));
{
    $array['file'][] = [//создается новый элемент-массив в ячейке "file" 
    массива $array
        'bla-bla-bla' => $file[1][$key], //пара ключ-значение
        'bla-bla-bla2' => $file[2][$key], //пара ключ-значение
 ];
}
```

Надеюсь, объяснил понятно.